# Transform iotop output to chart

Tags: gratis, linux

This command prints disk reads/writes per process every second:

```
iotop -bot > my.log
```

The output is like this:

```
11:19:25 Total DISK READ :       0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE :     198.47 K/s
11:19:25 Actual DISK READ:       0.00 B/s | Actual DISK WRITE:     339.69 K/s
    TIME  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
11:19:25   378 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    3.82 K/s  0.00 % 29.80 % postgres
11:19:25  1092 be/4 nico        0.00 B/s  164.12 K/s  0.00 %  0.20 % firefox -new-window [LS Thread]
11:19:25   961 be/4 nico        0.00 B/s   30.53 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % firefox -new-window [mozStorage #3]

11:19:26 Total DISK READ :      30.34 K/s | Total DISK WRITE :       3.79 K/s
11:19:26 Actual DISK READ:      45.51 K/s | Actual DISK WRITE:      98.61 K/s
    TIME  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN      IO    COMMAND
11:19:26 22866 be/4 nico       30.34 K/s    3.79 K/s  0.00 %  5.12 % firefox -new-window [IndexedDB #824]
11:19:26   378 be/3 root        0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.09 % virtualbox
```

I need a tool that takes this log file, and generates a chart that shows how reads/second evolved.

Requirements:

- Free
- Runs on Linux

Comment: Do you insist on that output being used (e.g. because you take it to another machine for evaluation)? If not, there are plenty of monitoring systems covering that.

Comment: Yes it must be able to parse the output from iotop, not from another monitoring tool.